# Memory ramifications when writing HTML during a cron job

Tags: php, apache, memory, cron

I have a script that is run by a cron job.

It's a standard PHP page that can also be run manually to achieve the same result as the cron.

When run manually I var_dump HTML onto the page so that I can debug and see what's going on.

My question is: Are there any memory ramifications of writing out HTML when running the page as a cron job?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "memory ramifications"?

Comment: Writing HTML to a browser whilst running a script must consume some memory. If the script isn't being run by a browser then the HTML won't be written out. So is the memory usage between the two scenarios different?